# Export Outlook Exchange folders to windows file system

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, vba, exchange, visual-basic

Currently using A VB macro to pull folders of emails to the windows file system but it isn't able to pull folders stored on an exchange server, Is this even possible? Using the VB script below

```
' SET STARTING FOLDER IN FODLER CHOOSER AS USERS [P DRIVE]
Const STARTING_FOLDER = "P:"

Dim objFSO As Object

' [COPY] THE OUTLOOK FOLDER
Sub CopyOutlookFolderToFileSystem()
    ExportController "Copy"
End Sub

' [MOVE] THE OUTLOOK FOLDER
Sub MoveOutlookFolderToFileSystem()
    ExportController "Move"
End Sub

' [USER] SELECTION OF FOLDER TO SAVE MESSAGES INTO ON SYSTEM
Sub ExportController(strAction As String)
    Dim olkFld As Outlook.MAPIFolder, strPath As String
    strPath = SelectFolder(STARTING_FOLDER)
    If strPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No Folder selected! Export cancelled.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Export Outlook Folder"
    Else
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set olkFld = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
        ExportOutlookFolder olkFld, strPath
        If LCase(strAction) = "move" Then olkFld.Delete
    End If
    Set olkFld = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing
End Sub

' FOR [ALL] MESSAGES IN THE FOLDER, EXPORT [ALL] MESSAGES
Sub ExportOutlookFolder(ByVal olkFld As Outlook.MAPIFolder, strStartingPath As String)
    Dim olkSub As Outlook.MAPIFolder, olkItm As Object, strPath As String, strMyPath As String, strSubejct As String, intCount As Integer
    strPath = strStartingPath & "\" & olkFld.Name
    objFSO.CreateFolder strPath
    For Each olkItm In olkFld.Items
        strSubject = "[From] " & olkItm.SenderName & " [Subject] " & RemoveIllegalCharacters(olkItm.Subject)
        strFilename = strSubject & ".msg"
        intCount = 0
        Do While True
            strMyPath = strPath & "\" & strFilename
            If objFSO.FileExists(strMyPath) Then
                intCount = intCount + 1
                strFilename = strSubject & " (" & intCount & ").msg"
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
        olkItm.SaveAs strMyPath, olMSG
        ChangeTimeStamp strMyPath, olkItm.ReceivedTime
    Next
    For Each olkSub In olkFld.Folders
        ExportOutlookFolder olkSub, strPath
    Next
    Set olkFld = Nothing
    Set olkItm = Nothing
End Sub

Function SelectFolder(varStartingFolder As Variant) As String

    ' STANDARD ERROR HANDLING
    Dim objFolder As Object, objShell As Object
    On Error Resume Next

    ' CREATE A DIALOG OBJECT FOR FOLDER SELECTION & RETURN THE FOLDER [PATH]
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select the System folder you want to export to ...", 0, varStartingFolder)
    If TypeName(objFolder) <> "Nothing" Then SelectFolder = objFolder.self.Path

    ' STANDARD ERROR HANDLING
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objShell = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function RemoveIllegalCharacters(strValue As String) As String

    ' REMOVE [ALL CHARACTERS] THAT CANNOT BE CONTAINED IN A FILESYSTEM NAME
    RemoveIllegalCharacters = strValue
    RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, "<", "")
    RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, ">", "")
    RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, ":", "")
    RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, Chr(34), "'")
    RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, "/", "")
    RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, "\", "")
    RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, "|", "")
    RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, "?", "")
    RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, "*", "")
End Function

Sub ChangeTimeStamp(strFile As String, datStamp As Date)

    ' SAVE IN THE FILENAME THE [TIME] AND [DATE] OF THE [ORIGINAL] MESSAGE BEING SENT/RECIEVED
    Dim objShell As Object, objFolder As Object, objFolderItem As Object, varPath As Variant, varName As Variant
    varName = Mid(strFile, InStrRev(strFile, "\") + 1)
    varPath = Mid(strFile, 1, InStrRev(strFile, "\"))
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace(varPath)
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(varName)
    objFolderItem.ModifyDate = CStr(datStamp)
    Set objShell = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objFolderItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As you didn´t specify if that MUST be done via old school VB script... I would using [Exchange Webservices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877045(v=exchg.140).aspx) and then exporting the emails via that way to a fileserver. You do not need an Outlook client here. However you need to write something in C#. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn672317(v=exchg.150).aspx) is an example:

```
private static void ExportMIMEEmail(ExchangeService service)
{
    Folder inbox = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
    ItemView view = new ItemView(1);
    view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);

    // This results in a FindItem call to EWS.
    FindItemsResults<Item> results = inbox.FindItems(view);

    foreach (var item in results)
    { 
        PropertySet props = new PropertySet(EmailMessageSchema.MimeContent);

        // This results in a GetItem call to EWS.
        var email = EmailMessage.Bind(service, item.Id, props);

        string emlFileName = @"C:\export\email.eml";
        string mhtFileName = @"C:\export\email.mht";

        // Save as .eml.
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(emlFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            fs.Write(email.MimeContent.Content, 0, email.MimeContent.Content.Length);
        }

        // Save as .mht.
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(mhtFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            fs.Write(email.MimeContent.Content, 0, email.MimeContent.Content.Length);
        }
    }
}
```